# Cómo seleccionar un grupo de elementos en Javascript

Tags: javascript

Mi duda es por qué si pongo un índice en "document.getElementsByTagName('td')[0]" sí que pinta del color que marco, en cambio si no se lo pongo, no hace nada. Sin el índice no debería pintar cualquier "td" que seleccione?

Aquí dejo el código:

```js
var elementoTable = document.createElement("tbody");

for (f = 0; f < 30; f++) {

  var elementoTR = document.createElement("tr");


  for (c = 0; c < 30; c++) {


    var elementoTD = document.createElement("td");
    elementoTR.appendChild(elementoTD);

  }

  elementoTable.appendChild(elementoTR);

}

document.getElementById("tablerodibujo").appendChild(elementoTable);
document.getElementById('tablerodibujo').addEventListener("click", colorear_amarillo, false);

function colorear_amarillo() {

  document.getElementsByTagName('td')[0].style.backgroundColor = "#000";
}
```

```css
td {
  background-color: green;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
}

tr {
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
}
```

```html
<table id="tablerodibujo"></table>
```

Comment: dices si solo pones `document.getElementsByTagName('td')` ?

Comment: Sí, a eso me refería

Comment: Y porque no los coges por `class` y le pones la clase a los que quieras coger ya que la clase se puede repetir?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debes de aplicar el "EventListener" a cada celda. Una forma de hacerlo es usando un `for`.

> Nota: El código del amarillo es `#ffff00` no `#000`.

Ejemplo:

```js
var elementoTable = document.createElement("tbody");

for (f = 0; f < 30; f++) {

  var elementoTR = document.createElement("tr");


  for (c = 0; c < 30; c++) {


    var elementoTD = document.createElement("td");
    elementoTR.appendChild(elementoTD);

  }

  elementoTable.appendChild(elementoTR);

}

document.getElementById("tablerodibujo").appendChild(elementoTable);
var celdas = document.getElementsByTagName("td");
for(var i = 0;i < celdas.length; i++) {
  celdas[i].addEventListener("click", colorear_amarillo, false);
}

function colorear_amarillo() {

  this.style.backgroundColor = "#ffff00";
}
```

```css
td {
  background-color: green;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
}

tr {
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
}
```

```html
<table id="tablerodibujo"></table>
```

Answer (score 1):

La seleccion document.getElementsByTagName('td') selecciona todos pero devuelve un array por lo que si haces .style.backgroundColor se lo haces al array no a los elementos.

Tendrias que recorrerlos todos

```
var arrayTd = document.getElementsByTagName('td');
var arrayLength = arrayTd.length;
for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
    arrayTd[i].style.backgroundColor = "#000";
}
```

Comment: Pero así lo que ocurre es que me cambian todas as celdas de color, y yo lo que quiero es clicar en una y que cambie esa solo, sea cual sea. Sin tener que marcarlo en el índice como tengo yo en el código inicial

Comment: Con tu codigo actual parece que lo que quieres es colorear todos. Para lo que dices  tienes que asignar el evento a cada td (no recuerdo exactamente si los td aceptan click) y luego hacer algo asi: elementoTD.addEventListener('click', colorear_amarillo, false); y luego function colorear_amarillo (e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    var target = e.target || e.srcElement,
        target.style.backgroundColor = "#000";
}De todas formas yo usaria JQuery, es mucho mas sencillo

Comment: ¿Y por qué no le asignas un id único a cada td y lo cambias por el id?

Answer (score 0):

El método `getElementsByTagName("selectName")` retorna un **Array** agrupando los elementos  del `tag` seleccionado, y como todo **Array** debes iterar con cada elemento para poder accionarlos, una forma de iterar puede ser la siguiente.

Ejemplo:

```js
Array=document.getElementsByTagName("td");
for(var e = 0; e < Array.length; e++){
 Array[e].onclick = function(){
  this.classList.toggle("select");
 };
};
```

```css
td {
 color:red;
}
.select {
 color:green;
}
```

```html
<h1>Bienvenido a StackOverflow ;))</h1>
<table>
 <tr><td>Item 1</td></tr>
 <tr><td>Item 2</td></tr>
 <tr><td>Item 3</td></tr>
</table>
```